# Sync Walkman with Ubuntu

Tags: sync, sony

Can anyone help me with synchronizing my Sony Walkman with Ubuntu?
I have tried everything and searched everywhere but nothing works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tried a lot and JSymphonic didn't work for me! but fortunately I found gMTP in Ubuntu Software center. Through this app I can now manage my Music on my Sony Walkman.

Its realy easy to install. Just type gMTP in Ubuntu software Center and install.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Jsymphonic](http://symphonic.sourceforge.net/page.php?4).

> JSymphonic is a free open source program for managing Sony's Walkmans. It can transfer music from/to Walkmans. Its aim is to replace SonicStage.

It is written in Java so you must run it:

```
java -jar JSymphonic*.jar
```

But before that install `java`

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Comment: As of 2024 the link doesn't seem to work anymore.